# Gson decode json

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using PHP to generate `Json` that was grabbed from a database query. The result looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "title":"Title 1",
        "description":"This is description 1",
        "add_date":"2013-07-17 10:07:53"
    },{
        "title":"Title 2",
        "description":"This is description 2",
        "add_date":"2013-07-17 10:07:53"
    }
]
```

I am using Gson to parse the data, like this:

```
public class Search{

    public Search(String text){
        try{

            // Snipped (gets the data from the website)

            Gson json = new Gson();
            Map<String, Event> events = json.fromJson(resultstring, new TypeToken<Map<String, Event>>(){}.getType());

            System.out.print(events.get("description"));

        }catch(IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}

class Event {
    private String description;
}
```

here is the message I am getting while trying to run the code:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3

How would I loop through each one to get the value of `description`, or `title` or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several corrections on what you are doing and you should be good to go:

```
class Event {
    private String description;
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("add_date") private String addDate;

   public getDescription() {
       return description;
   }
}


 public Search(String text){
    try{

        // Snipped (gets the data from the website)

        Gson json = new Gson();
        Event[] events = json.fromJson(resultstring, Event[].class);

        System.out.print(events[0].getDescription());

    }catch(IOException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

I have corrected your bean class and changed the type of what you convert to (array of `Event`, because this is what you actually are getting from the PHP service);

Comment: Works, but I am getting this error: `cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SerialzedName
  location: class Event`. Also, Why do you Serialze it?

Comment: @RyanNaddy This is annotation that tells that you do not use the direct correspondence of field name and json property. However, you need to import the annotation. And that is what error you are getting